# How to hide user profile fields defined as object properties?

Tags: 7, users

I know it is possible to hide most fields defined on `/admin/config/people/accounts/fields` on the user edit form `/user/<uid>/edit` by using the HOOK_form_alter function in a custom module like this targeting `user_profile_form`:

```
$form['field_account_myfield']['#access'] = 0;
```

But how to hide user profile form fields the right way (no CSS tricks)?

in my case the URL is `/user/<uid>/edit/Profil`. These are the fields you can define with the core profile module enabled on `/admin/config/people/profile`.

They are defined as object properties in the `$form['#user']` object, e.g.:

```
$form['#user']->profile_address
```

`unset()` and `['#access'] = 0` does not seem to work.

Comment: [Profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) module?

Comment: _They are defined as object properties in the $form['#user'] object_ those are the values attached to an entity object; they're not related to form fields. Look in the `$form` array, you'll find the actual form fields in there somewhere

Comment: @Clive - I can't seem to find it. I tried searching for the profile field name (profile_myfield) on all forms on the page with [Search Krumo](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_krumo), but the field name only appears in the `$form['#user']` object.